# How to I grab the text of numbered Textboxes dynamically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, textbox

I am creating a contacts add and I want to add the option to add more than 1 phone numbers.
I allow the creation of more textboxes for the user to add number with this button:

```
        private void AddPhoneNumberButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int numberOfTextBoxes = PhoneNumberStackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBox>().Count();

            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            txtbox.Name = $"PhoneNumberTextBox{numberOfTextBoxes}";
            txtbox.Width = 200;
            txtbox.Background = Brushes.White;
            txtbox.Margin = new Thickness(0,10,0,0);
            PhoneNumberStackPanel.Children.Add(txtbox);
        }
```

Now how to I refer to those textboxes dynamically. Like if I want to grab all the text in these textboxes with this loop:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < PhoneNumberStackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBox>().Count() ; i++){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(TextBox tb in PhoneNumberStackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    string text = tb.Text;
}
```

also consider replacing StackPanel with `ItemsControl`:

```
private void AddPhoneNumberButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfTextBoxes = PhoneNumberItemsControl.Items.Count;

    TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
    txtbox.Name = $"PhoneNumberTextBox{numberOfTextBoxes}";
    txtbox.Width = 200;
    txtbox.Background = Brushes.White;
    txtbox.Margin = new Thickness(0,10,0,0);
    PhoneNumberItemsControl.Items.Add(txtbox);
}

foreach(TextBox tb in PhoneNumberItemsControl.Items.OfType<TextBox>())
{
}
```

next step which you can make is moving TextBoxes into `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. (it becomes a "must-do" as soon as you need visual structure more complex than a single element)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why I was so focused on using the names I overlooked the simpler solution! I will also change to ItemControl.

Comment: @KostasSoulios If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)